# Saving file as a different file name using Filestream

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext

I am using the code below to save a pdf using itextsharp. Problem is evertime it saves, it overwrites the previous file. Is there a way so that a new file is created eachtime with a different name?

```
    Dim Doc1 As New Document
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("PDFs")
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & "/Doc1.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))

    Doc1.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If readability does not matter, then use a `Guid`, like this:

```
Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.txt", Guid.NewGuid())
```

If readability does matter, then I would suggest appending the date/time, like this:

```
Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("PDF_{0}.txt", DateTime.Now.[Date].Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.[Date].Day.ToString() + DateTime.Now.[Date].Year.ToString() + "_" & DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: append a `Guid` to the filename

```
Dim fileName As String = Guid.NewGuid() & "_Doc1.pdf"
PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & "/" & fileName , FileMode.Create))
```

Comment: Says operator '&' is not defined?